# Detect eventlet environment?

Tags: python, eventlet

I have some modules which are sometimes imported from within an eventlet environment, and sometimes from a regular python environment.  I would like to detect this so that I can conditionally invoke things like `monkey_patch` and `debug.hub_blocking_detection`.

Is there a reliable way for a piece of python code to discover whether it's running in an eventlet environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what Kombu/Celery uses: https://github.com/ask/kombu/blob/master/kombu/syn.py

Comment: Great, and I can even import that straight from kombu :-)

Comment: Sure, you can!  Other libraries use it too, and it won't disappear